Union the results with loop to call function for each table row
I am pretty new to Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) queries. I have a stored function, that takes a string as a parameter, does some querying around that input and return a data table.
QueryFunc(input: string)
{
   //does some queries and result a table
}

I can union the result by running like:
union QueryFunc('input1'), QueryFunc('input2')

But as the inputs set are dynamic which it can be got by other query like blew as a column.
let inputSets = xxx
xxx
xxx;

But when I want to loop each of the inputs to call the func QueryFunc and union the result like below(input is a column in inputSets):
inputSets | union QueryFunc(input)

It reported error that:

Semantic error: 'union' operator: Failed to resolve table or scalar
expression named 'input'

Is there any way I can loop each of the query results and invoke func QueryFunc and union all the result together?

If the QueryFunc only gives you a scalar value, you could do the loop like this:
let data = pack_array("a", "b", "c", "d");
let queryFunc = (input:string) { strcat(input, "1") };
range i from 0 to array_length(data) - 1 step 1
| extend Result = queryFunc (data[i])
| summarize ResultList = make_list(Result)
| project ConcatenatedResults = strcat_array(ResultList, "")

Result is:

When the QueryFunc gives you a table, I think there is no way, at least that I know of, to make the unions dynamic in a loop.

Thanks, yes if the QueryFunc return a scalar value, it is possible to do this in a loop call to iterate every input from set inputs and call func QueryFunc,
But I think my question is a very common case for KQL, say if you want to get a full data(a table), but each data come from a query/func which accept a string input and then output a table.
But I have a sets of input which coming from another query and I want to loop each of the input from the inputs set and call the QueryFunc, finally summaries all the result tables together.

From the error message, the result of both function and the result from let statement should be similar. Your function returns different type and let statement is of different type. Below is the sample code which joins a function and table.
let QueryFunc = (a:long) {
  datatable(Date:datetime, Event:string, MoreData:dynamic) [
    datetime(1910-06-11), "Born", dynamic({"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}),
    datetime(1930-01-01), "Enters Ecole Navale", dynamic({"key1":"value3", "key2":"value4"}),
    datetime(1953-01-01), "Published first book", dynamic({"key1":"value5", "key2":"value6"}),
    datetime(1997-06-25), "Died", dynamic({"key1":"value7", "key2":"value8"}),
]
| where strlen(Event) > a
| extend key2 = MoreData.key2
| project Event
};
let Table_sample=   datatable( Event:string) [
    "Born",
    "Published",
];
union QueryFunc(12),Table_sample

This query unions the result from QueryFunc() function and Table_sample.
demo

I think he wants to loop over the union statement, which is IMHO not possible. And the input after the union in his question is unknown because after the union operator is a different scope.

Oh, I understood now his requirement. As you said, only when QueryFunc returns scalar value, it is possible to in Kusto. I will check if there is some workaround when QueryFunc returns tabular value.

Yes. actually I want to loop over the union statement to call function QueryFunc for each input in the set of inputset, and the inputset is created by another query. is that possible?

I would say with union it is not possible.

Is there any other ways can met the requirement?
Actually I don't know why KQL does not support for/loop keywrods, this is basic I think.

It seems we don't have a solution on this in kusto func/queries, but this could be achieved by using power automate to create a cloud automation workflow and it support foreach mechanism which can work individually on each result.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
